# $.getJSON(p) Remote Request Fails

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp, getjson

Im trying to retrieve some information from a json using the getJSON jquery method from a remote source.
Sample url that is not working:

```
https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/store/api/chihiro/00_09_000/container/GR/en/999/EP0001-NPEB00932_00-GASSASSINS000001
```

When the url above is set as json fails due to cross-origin policy.
So making it jsonp request (adding the &callback=? on the end of url) returns nothing.
I have noticed with jsonp request the request passes(waiting for store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com on browser displaying) but returns nothing.
Also noticed when jsonp url enter in browser returns this string:

```
{"codeName":"ResourceDoesNotExist"}
```

I tried the same script with yahoo json apis and working fine.
Sample url that works:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20answers.search%20where%20query%3D%22cars%22%20and%20category_id%3D2115500137%20and%20type%3D%22resolved%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $.getJSON('https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/store/api/chihiro/00_11_000/container/GR/en/999/EP0001-NPEB00932_00-GASSASSINS000001&callback=?',
        {},
        function (data) {
            $.each( data, function ( i, val ) {
                var age_limit=val['age_limit'];
                $(".age_limit").append(age_limit+'<br>');
            });
        })
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="age_limit"></ul>
</body>
```

[Working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LY444/)
[Not working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LY444/1/)

I have also tried the abole example as ajax and pure javascript but the results was the same.
Is sonyentertainmentnetwork blocking json as jsonp remote access somehow or what?

Thank you.

Comment: Does the sony API you are using specifically allow JSON-P? The API has to implement JSON-P in order for it to be available. Check the API documentation.

Comment: Does this remote url support JSONP?  It needs to wrap the JSON data it is returning in a callback method that you (or jQuery) specifies e.g. `myCallback({ "some": "data", "from": "the server" })`

Comment: @compid I dont think the have any documentation regarding the api. At least to my knowledge.

Comment: Is this an official API? If not, it is very likely that you won't be able to retrieve data via AJAX. A workaround would be to build a backend that would make the API call for you (JSON proxy)

Comment: @jandersen Eeem, well probably don't(!). That's why it returns {"codeName":"ResourceDoesNotExist"}. Check my question

Comment: @compid No, it is not an official one! Found it in some xml files while searching how to do what i wanted. Wouldn't that require a lot of resources?

Comment: You will have to look at the documentation. JSON-P only works if the API provider implemented it. If implemented, the API will look for something like a `&callback=` parameter and wrap the data with the specified callback method, as @jandersen said.

Comment: I'll request API documentation from Sony.. !Fail! Thank you

Comment: I am writing an answer regarding a workaround using a JSON proxy

Comment: In general, you can't make Ajax calls to third party services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are encountering this issue because JSON-P is a feature implemented by the server, or API provider. The sony API you are using does not implement JSON-P, and therefore you cannot simply append `&callback=something` at the end of your URL to get JSON-P to work.

One workaround for this problem is to have a server backend that makes the request to the API (effectively creating a proxy). When servers make a request in the backend, it does not encounter the Cross Origin issue your browser does. There are services out there that provide this functionality if you don't want to set up your own backend, though there may be fees/limitations.

jsonp.jit.su is one of such services. jsonp.jit.su implements JSON-P, and can make a request to an API that does not support JSON-P. To use it, simply specify your ultimate API endpoint as the `url` parameter, and specify your callback function as the `callback` parameter, as follows:

http://jsonp.jit.su/?callback=myCallback&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstore.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com%2Fstore%2Fapi%2Fchihiro%2F00_09_000%2Fcontainer%2FGR%2Fen%2F999%2FEP0001-NPEB00932_00-GASSASSINS000001

Comment: The request passes using http://jsonp.jit.su/?callback=&url=... but returns lots of "undefined" as html. But probably that is my scripts error.

Comment: The URL I gave in my answer you should work for the url you provided in the question. You may have to URLencode it.

Comment: Well i will use this method only after exhausting all my other alternatives. Nevertheless i'll accept your answer because it solves the issue in my question. Thank you

Comment: Actually this doen't work because the url doesn't return a valid json. The whole script has to be inside [], in order to be valid. Thats why im getting undefined responses(?)

Comment: So yes i defined a variable like that var jsoned = [data]; and then $.each(jsoned, function(i,val) { ...same as before } and worked.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. json.jit.su is supposed to return the exact same thing as the original api call, except the response is wrapped with a function call.